# Creating a program to tell the user if a number is divisible by 5

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that does what the title says, by divisible by 5 that means integer values only. here is the code so far although it is incomplete:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int x;
    cout << "Enter a number to see if its divisable by 5" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    x = x / 5;
    if (x ==)
    {
        cout << "yes it is divisible by 5 and the value is" << x << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "no its not divisable by 5" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am stuck as to what to put for the if statement so that it recognises if the number assigned to x is divisible by 5 or not. Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this (use the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) % operator instead)

```
cin >> x;
 //x = x / 5; remove this
if (x % 5 == 0)
{
    cout << "yes it is divisible by 5 and the value is" << x/5 << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "no its not divisable by 5" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I will try this , however x/5 does not have to equal 0 , it has to equal any whole number . will your code accommodate for this ?

Comment: thank you this works . So modulo  (%) is the remainder  ?

Comment: @FlewittConnor yes it finds the remainder, check the link also in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use modulo `%` instead of `/` in `x = x / 5;`

modulo gives reminder 25%5=0, where as 25/5=5

In the `if (x ==)` statement put `x==0`

Comment: Thank you I have got it to work. Can you please explain to me what it means by  25%5=0 ? is modulo the remainder ?

Comment: yes modulo % is reminder of division, '/' gives quotient of division